# Error con método especial cmp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

[image: El código no me funciona y lo hice igual al libro]

He puesto el código tal como el libro que estoy aprendiendo, pero no me funciona con la función `__cmp__`, no se porque, por favor ayúdenme. Acá dejo el código que me olvido ponerlo, pero ya lo puse, estoy aprendiendo los objetos.

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Palabra:
  """Clase para mostrar el método __cmp__"""

  def __init__(self, contenido):
    self.contenido = contenido

  def __cmp__(self, otro):

    if self.contenido > otro.contenido:
      return 1
    elif self.contenido < otro.contenido:
      return -1
    else:
      return 0

larga = Palabra("supercalifragilisticoespialidoso")

corta = Palabra("bah")

if (larga > corta):
  print(larga.contenido + " es mayor que " + corta.contenido)
else:
  print(larga.contenido + " No es mayor que " + corta.contenido)
input()
```

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, no como imagen. Nadie va a retipear el código para probarlo.

Comment: Debes poner el código como texto, y no en imagen, si quieres ayuda. Como el problema es conceptual, solo te diré que el método mágico `__cmp__` [no está](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8276983/1545868) en Python 3. En su lugar usa `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__eq__`, etc. [PEP 207](https://peps.python.org/pep-0207/)

Answer (score 1):

Como puse en mi comentario, **cmp** no está más en python3 y [ha sido removido](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons). En su defecto usar alguno de los otros [métodos disponibles](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__):

```
__lt__(self, other) # (less-than)
__le__(self, other) # (less-equal)
__eq__(self, other) # (equal)
__ne__(self, other) # (not-equal)
__gt__(self, other) # (greater-than)
# etc...
```

Entonces, para arreglar tu código, solo hay que cambiar `def __cmp__(self, otro):` por

```
def __gt__(self, otro):
    # El resto del codigo permanece igual.
```

Finalmente debes tener cuidado con un par de consideraciones:

1- No se cual sea tu criterio para saber qué una cadena *es mayor* que otra. Python, como muchos lenguajes toman el orden de cada caracter para comprobarlo. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> 'rst' > 'a'
True
>>> 'rstuvw' > 'rw' # 'r'='r' pero 's'<'w', así que da False
False
```

Si estás comparando longitud entonces usa la función `len()`

2- Si intercambias los valores:

```
corta = Palabra("supercalifragilisticoespialidoso")
larga = Palabra("bah")
```

El resulado será: `bah es mayor que supercalifragilisticoespialidoso`, igual que si no se hubieran intercambiado las variables. ¿Por qué?
Estás retornando un valor, `-1`, que también se evalúa como `True`, similar a `1`.

```
>>> bool(-1) == bool(1) == True
True
```

Para arreglarlo, eliminar estas dos líneas, son innecesarias:

```
elif self.contenido < otro.contenido:
  return -1
```